# EXCEL: Reordering a list of items according to another list containing keywords

Tags: excel, excel-formula

On Excel, I have a list of items on column A that's ordered, and a list of corresponding items on column B that's unordered. Column A's items each contain a keyword that's to be matched to their corresponding item in column B. How do I reorder column B's items so that they match the order in column A?

My current data:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Table | 3_Chair |
| Chair | 2_Eraser |
| Pen | 4_Table |
| Eraser | 1_Pen |

Desired output:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Table | 4_Table |
| Chair | 3_Chair |
| Pen | 1_Pen |
| Eraser | 2_Eraser |

Comment: *Column A's items each contain a keyword that's to be matched to their corresponding item in column B.* Isn't that the other way around? Or can Column A values contain more than 1 word?

Comment: What you're literally asking is not possible with Excel formulas. If you want the results matched e,g, in column `C`, then it's a simple case of *INDEX/MATCH*: in cell `C2` use `=INDEX($B$2:$B$5,MATCH("*"&$A2,$B$2:$B$5,0))`.

Answer (score 2):

With ms365, try:

[image]

Formula in `D1`:

```
=LET(x,A1:A4,y,B1:B4,HSTACK(x,XLOOKUP("*_"&x,y,y,,2)))
```

Comment: It's hard to get used to the fact that `MATCH` is dead in M365.

Comment: I used `MATCH()` in the original answer but it's just more verbose that way @VBasic2008

Comment: Sure. I meant more like it's hard to remember (old habits) that there is [XMATCH](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xmatch-function-d966da31-7a6b-4a13-a1c6-5a33ed6a0312) now, with the 3rd argument's default parameter `0` and a little more functionality. Microsoft 'swears' that it's better (could not find the article though).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply sort that second column, but you need to select it first (don't select the title), like in this simple example (also mind the choice I made in the question):

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks. I think my example was too simplistic. Unfortunately the order in column A is not alphabetical. Let me change my example.

Answer (score 0):

This will work also with Excel 365

`=INDEX(B2:B5,MATCH(A2:A5,TEXTAFTER(B2:B5,"_"),0))`

[image]

If Excel 365 is not on current channel, `TEXTAFTER` has to be replaced by `MID`